# stl : map of vectors - begin() address

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stl

I've been fighting for several hours to understand why `begin()` of vector within a map doesn't return the same address if I point to the `vector.begin()` itself or the `second.begin()` member of the map.

Let me explain:

I have a class containing a map which key is an `int` and its content a vector of `int`. I have to go through the map and keep in memory the position where I was 'just before', so I also have another map of iterators (of the first map).

So, I would like to get something like:

- map1 : <2,<3,8,1,3,7,1>>
- map2 : <8,<6,9,1,3>>
- map3 : <1,<3,1>>
- etc.

*To make it simpler, in my code, the `T_IPC_CommandId` is just an enum of `int`.*

I have a method called `Add(int TopCommand, int Command)` which fills/creates the map of vectors of commands. For example, to create `map3`, I will code:

```
Add(1,3), Add(1,1)
```

I have a method called `GetNext(int Command)` which returns the next `int`, in the map pointed by `Command`. For example in `map2`, calling `Get(8)` will return `6`, and the next call will return `9`, then `1`, `3` and `0` for the next calls.

In order to know which `int` I will return, I need to keep track, for each map, what is the next `int` to return. So, I use a `IPC_CommandId_Pointer` which is a map which key is the command itself and holds the iterator where I am in the map. And here is the problem:

At each `Add()` call, I initialise this `IPC_CommandId_Pointer` to the beginning of main map. Like this:

```
        void T_ListOfCommand::Add(T_IPC_CommandId   Top_CommandId, T_IPC_CommandId IPC_CommandId)
    {
        T_IPC_CommandId_Vec_Iter Vec_Iter;
        T_IPC_CommandId_Vec      Vec;

        if ((IPC_CommandId_Map.find(Top_CommandId)) == IPC_CommandId_Map.end())
        {

            IPC_CommandId_Map[Top_CommandId].clear();
        }
        IPC_CommandId_Map[Top_CommandId].push_back(IPC_CommandId);

        // Repeated at each add, but don't care ...
        Vec_Iter = IPC_CommandId_Map[Top_CommandId].begin();
        IPC_CommandId_Pointer[Top_CommandId] = Vec_Iter;
    }
```

The problem I have is that, at each `IPC_CommandId_Map[Top_CommandId].push_back(IPC_CommandId)`, the `IPC_CommandId_Map[Top_CommandId].begin()` doesn't return the same address.

Now, when replacing the:

```
Vec_Iter = IPC_CommandId_Map[Top_CommandId].begin();
IPC_CommandId_Pointer[Top_CommandId] = Vec_Iter;
```

With:

```
Vec = IPC_CommandId_Map[Top_CommandId];
IPC_CommandId_Pointer[Top_CommandId] = Vec.begin();
```

This works fine.

I'm supposing to point to the same location when using the `begin()` in the map, or when dereferencing the vector, isn't it? Well, it seems not.

If someone could explain me the difference, that would be great.

Comment: Can you narrow your question down to *relevant* code?

Comment: The code `Vec = IPC_CommandId_Map[Top_CommandId];` **copies** the element of the map to the variable `Vec`.

Answer (score 1):

`vector::begin()` is not guaranteed to return the same address each time!

If `std::vector::push_back()` causes reallocation of the vectors data (since its data has to be continuous), the iterator (address) which `begin()` returns will be different.

And (as [The Paramagnetic Croissant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3477950/the-paramagnetic-croissant) stated in the comment) the code `Vec = IPC_CommandId_Map[Top_CommandId];` copies the element of the map to the variable Vec.

Comment: The fact that push_back() causes reallocation was not something that I knew.
Thank's you all for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

(Vocabulary check: you're not dereferencing anything, particularly not a vector.)

```
Vec_Iter = IPC_CommandId_Map[Top_CommandId].begin();
```

is an iterator into the vector in the map.
It becomes invalid when the vector is reallocated.
Every time the vector is reallocated you will get a different value for `begin()`.
It's a bad idea to store this iterator across calls to `push_back` or anything else that may invalidate an iterator.

```
Vec = IPC_CommandId_Map[Top_CommandId];
IPC_CommandId_Pointer[Top_CommandId] = Vec.begin();
```

is an iterator into the local copy `Vec`.
It becomes invalid as soon as the function returns.
It's a bad idea to store this iterator *anywhere* beyond `Vec`'s lifetime.

Overall, iterators should be considered transient and only be used in as small a scope as possible.

A much more robust solution is to store a "current index" for the vector instead of an iterator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers; in fact, both ways are "bad idea" and now, I understand why. 
But even if the second solutions "works a bit", does it means that it's not guaranteed in life time ?
I definitely agree that storing "current index" would have been better; but storing the iterator itself was something "nice" to perform. Well, at that time.